# 2sxc - Oqtane: Mobius Forms don't send mails

Tags: 2sxc, mobius

We are using Oqtane 3.4.2 and 2sxc 15.08.00. We have configured a contact form. If we send a Message we receive an error "An unexpected error occured while sending. Please try again. If it fails again, please send it by E-Mail.".

We try debugging. The exception is throwing in the method "FormController.ProcessForm()". The line is "foreach(var file in...". We have configured no files to upload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that your Oqtane doesn't have the mail server configured yet. could you check?

You can also find more details about the error in the logs/insights - see https://docs.2sxc.org/net-code/debug/insights.html

Comment: The mail server is congirured well. If I cancel the code "foreach(var file in..." in debugging mode, I receive the mails for the owner and the customer.

Comment: I believe this is a json-serialization issue, because we used to have Newtonsoft for JSON procesing. I believe our not-yet-released version is fixed - could you try to just manually copy the code from https://github.com/2sic/app-mobius-forms/blob/master/staging/api/FormController.cs#L75 ?

Comment: The code from github solves the problem. Thank you for the recommendation.